ViewFlipper stop playing next Video after first Video finished
I'm trying to make Image/Video slider using View Flipper
I add child of viewflipper with MaterialCardView, LinearLayout
and inside of LinearLayout I add textview and media (Image/Video)
I create the element programmatically using code like below:
val layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER


    for (i in 0 until 3) {  
        val cardView = MaterialCardView(myActivity)
        cardView.radius = 20f  
        cardView.layoutParams = layoutParams 
        bd.viewFlipper.addView(cardView)

        val linearLayout = LinearLayout(myActivity)
        linearLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT 
        )
        linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL 
        cardView.addView(linearLayout)

        val textView = AppCompatTextView(myActivity)
        textView.text = "Notifikasi ${i + 1}"  
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(myActivity, android.R.color.white)) 
        textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(myActivity, R.color.tertiary)) 
        textView.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15)  
        val textLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  
        )
        textView.layoutParams = textLayoutParams
        linearLayout.addView(textView)

        val mediaView: View = if (i == 0) { 
            val imageView = ImageView(myActivity)
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.about)
            imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER  
            imageView.id = View.generateViewId()
            imageView
        } else { 
            val videoView = VideoView(myActivity)
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + if (i == 1) R.raw.video2 else R.raw.video3))
            videoView.id = View.generateViewId()
            videoView
        }
        val mediaLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT 
        )
        mediaLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

        mediaView.layoutParams = mediaLayoutParams
        linearLayout.addView(mediaView)
    }

    bd.viewFlipper.inAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myActivity, android.R.anim.fade_in)
    bd.viewFlipper.outAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myActivity, android.R.anim.fade_out)

    for (i in 0 until bd.viewFlipper.childCount) {
        val cardView = bd.viewFlipper.getChildAt(i) as? MaterialCardView
        val linearLayout = cardView?.getChildAt(0) as? LinearLayout
        val mediaView = linearLayout?.getChildAt(1)  

        if (mediaView is VideoView) {
            mediaView.setOnPreparedListener { 
                mediaView.start()
                bd.viewFlipper.stopFlipping()
            }

            mediaView.setOnCompletionListener {
                mediaView.stopPlayback()
                bd.viewFlipper.showNext()
                bd.viewFlipper.startFlipping()
            }
        }
    }

    bd.viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000)  
    bd.viewFlipper.startFlipping()  
    

all is working fine when first video play, but after it's stop and next video play it just won't play anymore.
everything work perfectly if I never put MaterialCardView, LinearLayout, etc. and just straight add Image or Video into viewFlipper
But I want to put another element to beautify the apps.
any help is appreaciated.
